# How to stop execute functionalities of the component in other tabs for looped tabs in Angular - Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this weird problem in Angular.

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab *ngFor="let subject of subjects" label="subject.name">
   <my-form></my-form>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

*Note: subjects size is dynamic, it can be more than 2 or more.*

**my-form.component.html**

```
<input *ngIf="isShow" type="text"></input>
<button (click)="toggleInputShow()"></button>
```

**my-form.component.ts**

```
isShow= false;

onInit() {}

toggleInputShow() {
 this.isShow = !this.isShow;
}
```

The problem is, for example I have 3 subjects, so I have 3 tabs displayed.
Then I click the second tab, then click the button so input will show.
But then when I moved to the first tab, the input is showing also.

What I want is if I show the input in the second tab, it showed only be showed in the second tab and hidden in first and third tab.

Can anyone help me with this? Pretty please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve by this way.

```
 <md-tab-group>
    <md-tab *ngFor="let subject of subjects" label="subject.name">
      <my-form></my-form>
    </md-tab>
 </md-tab-group>
```

**my-form.component.ts**

```
<input *ngIf="subject.isShow" type="text"></input>
<button (click)="toggleInputShow(subject)"></button>
```

**my-form.component.ts**

```
  toggleInputShow(subject) {
    subject.isShow = !subject.isShow;
  }
```

May be by default you need to initialize **isShow** property in each subject.